# Dealing with log4j vulnerability in ArcGIS Enterprise products

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, security

Is there a way to deal with the log4j vulnerability in the ArcGIS Enterprise products?

- Portal for ArcGIS
- ArcGIS Server
- ArcGIS Datastore

Answer (score 4):

At the time of writing, Esri have posted a [**blog**](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-enterprise/administration/arcgis-software-and-cve-2021-44228-aka-log4shell-aka-logjam/) on the vulnerabilities associated with the Log4j library.

> Esri is actively investigating the impact of the Log4j library critical vulnerabilities (CVE-2021-44228) disclosed on December 9, 2021 and associated CVE’s (2021-45046, 2021-4104) disclosed on December 14, 2021, as some Esri products contain this common logging tool.

Official patches are not yet available, however, they have written mitigation scripts, with instructions for running them, for the following components:

- [ArcGIS Server](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000026951)
- [Portal for ArcGIS](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000026950)
- [ArcGIS Data Store](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000026949)
- [ArcGIS GeoEvent Server](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000026956)
- [ArcGIS Workflow Manager Server](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000026970)
- [ArcGIS GeoEnrichment Server](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000026982)

---